# Add property to DTO during serialization in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-serializer

In a Controller, during serialization, using the [Symfony Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html), I need to dynamically add a property `portal` to an object, depending on an outside `$portal` value, which is a query argument.

```php
$content = $response->getContent();
# Switching the complete class, just to set a property
$type = match ( $portal ) {
    'portal_a' => FooBarContainsCustomPropA::class."[]",
    'portal_b' => FooBarContainsCustomPropB::class."[]",
};
$my_object = $this->serializer->deserialize(
    $response->getContent(),
    $type,
    'json',
    [ UnwrappingDenormalizer::UNWRAP_PATH => '[data][someObjectList]' ]
);
```

In this scenario, I am using custom objects, extending a main class, to set the property (hard-coded). I am searching for a better solution as this way, I am forced to add one additional class per `portal`/ case, which will get unmaintainable with possibly hundreds of user defined portals.

```php
# This solution depends on someone manually adding classes
# when a user adds a portal:

class FooBar {
   # various properties
}

class FooBarContainsCustomPropA extends FooBar {
   public string $portal = 'Portal A';
}

class FooBarContainsCustomPropB extends FooBar {
   public string $portal = 'Portal B';
}
```

Current output + the desired result:

```
{
   "some": "prop",
   "another": "property",
+   "portal": "Portal B"
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to accomplish, what's wrong with your solution, what are your constraints, and where `$portal` is coming from.

Comment: Why `$portal` can't be part of the payload directly? Or if not, can't you add `portal` to the payload after receiving it (`$payload['portal'] = $portal`) and deserialize that?

Comment: @yivi how would I get the data from the payload `$request->getContent()` into a DTO that gets queried and serialized?